# JAVA I keep getting arraynextoutofboundsexception can someone tell me why?

Tags: java

I cant seem to figure it out is it possible that someone can tell me why?

```
public class Display {

    private int width,height;
    public int [] pixels;

    public int [] tiles = new int[64 * 64];
    private Random random = new Random();

    public Display(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        pixels = new int [width*height]; // 50400

        for (int i = 0; i < 64 * 64; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt (0xffffff);
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
            tiles[i] = random.nextInt (0xffffff);
        }
    }
    public void render() {
        for (int y = 0; y <height; y++) {
            if (y < 0 || y >= height) break;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                if (x < 0 || x >=width) break;
                int tileIndex = (x / 16) + (y / 16) * 64;
                pixels[x+y*width] = tiles[tileIndex];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First:  **where** does your application tell you that you have an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Because you have an array index that's out of bounds.  The exception "stack trace" tells you what line the error occurs on and, IIRC, what the bad index value was.  Use a debugger or insert println statements to look at your array size and index value on the failing statement, then figure out what's wrong.  This is called "debugging", and you need to learn how to do it.

Comment: When I use the duilt in debugger in eclipse  tiles[i] = random.nextInt (0xffffff); is lit up green. Im completly new to coding and not sure what to do.                                                 This is the error I get :                                                    Exception in thread "Display" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4096
 at com.game.luminous.Display.clear(Display.java:25)
 at com.game.luminous.MainClass.render(MainClass.java:95)
 at com.game.luminous.MainClass.run(MainClass.java:70)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Well, first you need to identify line 25 in Display.java.

Comment: The loop in `clear` is obviously wrong.  Beyond that I haven't analyzed.

Comment: tiles[i] = random.nextInt (0xffffff); this is on line 25.

Comment: Is it the one inside `clear`?  Look at the loop there.

Comment: Yeah it is inside clear

Comment: So what am I supposed to change?

Answer (score 0):

The ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is likely to occur at the assignment in the clear() method.
You are iterating from 0 to pixels.length. pixels.length is variable-sized (according to what is passed to the constructor). While iterating you assign values to tiles[i]. Tiles is a fixed sized array (64*64 = 4.096 entries). If width*height > 4096, the clear() method will fail if it tries to access tiles[4096] or above.

Maybe you wanted to iterate up to tiles.length only?